# Is it possible to set the default lens in Unity?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses

I am currently using Unity, and finding it on the whole very good. However, the Dash is not particularly useful to me, and I would like to set the default action on pressing the BFB (is it still called that?) to opening the docs lens, as that is generally the most useful one to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently not possible, however you can use the <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> keyboard shortcut to open it directly.

In 12.04 the plan is to just let you drag the lens from the dash and put it in your panel, but this isn't implemented yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make your own doc buttons by editing example.desktop and then clicking and dragging the file into the dash.  I personally made one that will connect to and desconnect from a file server I have.